# Django adding Slug with a CreateView

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to add a slug into the Django CreateView that I can use in my context for the page. for example I have tried this:

```
url(r'^registration/profile/(?P<slug>[\w\-\_]+)/?$', RegistrationView.as_view(),
                           name='registration_profile'),
```

view

```
class RegistrationView(BaseCreateView):
    form_class = AppUserIntroducerCreateForm
    template_name = "registration/register.html"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RegistrationView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['slug'] = self.slug.slug
        return context
```

but still get `AttributeError: 'RegistrationView' object has no attribute 'slug'`

Answer (score 1):

The slug is provided in `kwargs`, which is a dictionary.

```
context['slug'] = kwargs['slug']
```